# The apache deployment flask project browser cannot be displayed

Tags: python

I'm using ubuntu. After setting up the apache server, the flask project is also placed in the /var/www/ directory of apache. I am accessing the webpage through IP, but it has not been successful.

The information given by the browser is as follows:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your  request.
Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@gerenboke.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

This is just a part of the project log, as follows

```
[Thu Dec 28 14:52:31.386188 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 8781:tid 140229316835072] [remote 192.168.153.138:58358] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Dec 28 14:52:31.386201 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 8781:tid 140229316835072] [remote 192.168.153.138:58358]   File "/var/www/gerenboke.com/apphtml.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Thu Dec 28 14:52:31.386220 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 8781:tid 140229316835072] [remote 192.168.153.138:58358]     from App import create_app
[Thu Dec 28 14:52:31.386256 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 8781:tid 140229316835072] [remote 192.168.153.138:58358] ImportError: cannot import name create_app
```

Based on this, I still can't solve the problem

The content of my wsgi file is as follows:
#!/home/linux001/anaconda3/envs/new_env/bin/python

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/gerenboke.com/')
import logging

from App import create_app

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```